# Import monotouch DLL in XCODE 4

Tags: xcode, xcode4, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I want to know if I can make a dll in monotouch using monodevelop and then import this dll into a xcode 4 project to use it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried it myself but this seems to be a nice tutorial on the subject:
http://www.guidebee.biz/forum/viewthread.php?tid=172